# Pygame Music Queue not functioning

Tags: python, pygame

I've been trying to figure this out all day without success:
How do you set up a playlist of songs to play in pygame? The queue command doesn't seem to work for me. All that happens is that the first song I load will play all the way through and then the second won't start. The pygame documentation says this is all I need. Am I making an obvious mistake?

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init

screen=pygame.display.set_mode((800,450))
pygame.mixer.music.load('mimages\\sounds\\droll.wav')

pygame.mixer.music.play(0,0.0)
pygame.mixer.music.queue('mimages\\sounds\\hip2014.wav')


running=True
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
while running:
    clock.tick(2)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                running=False
                holdon=False
            if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key==pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running=False
                holdon=False
    print pygame.mixer.music.get_busy()
```

Comment: Two really dumb things to check (the kinds of mistakes I would definitely make…): (1) are you sure that `hip2014.wav` is the right name, and that pygame can play it (e.g., if you put it first). (2) is it possible that `droll.wav` ends with 5 minutes of silence or something silly?

Comment: Also, you can use `music.set_endevent` to make it post an event to you queue (that you can display or something) so you can see if thinks the first song never finished, or if it thinks it played two songs even though you only heard one, etc. That can be helpful for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

**The queue () function in the Pygame module does not work correctly.**

I created a function that works without queue () function.

I don't know why it doesn't work. :)

But luckily there's a code that works.

try it:

```
import pygame
import time
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
c = ["music1.mp3","music2.mp3","music3.mp3"] #you_can_add_more
x= 0

def music():
    pygame.init()
    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.mixer.music.load(c[x])
    pygame.mixer.music.play(0)
    que()

def que():
    global x, c
    pos = pygame.mixer.music.get_pos()
    if int(pos) == -1:
        x += 1
        pygame.mixer.music.load(c[x])
        pygame.mixer.music.play(0)

    root.after(1, que)

music()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This answer only provides an example without explanation. Please explain why/where OP went wrong, and why your answer should resolve the issue.

Comment: there is nothing to explain!

Comment: @user8777433 For starters, you can explain what you are using `tkinter` for, and how it manages to play the song after the previous one, in a non-blocking way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
pygame.mixer.music.load('mimages\\sounds\\droll.wav')
pygame.mixer.music.queue('mimages\\sounds\\hip2014.wav')
pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

This allows you to build up the queue, then play through it all at once. If you want to play different files later, try running `pygame.mixer.music.stop()` (if the queue hasn't finished yet) then use `load()` (optionally followed by one or more `queue()` statements) then `play()` again.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that. In fact, his code is almost identical to the main example for `queue()`.

Comment: @abarnert - I saw this setup in some code samples I googled, so I figured I'd throw it out there. Wouldn't be the first time the docs were incorrect (or possibly outdated), right?

Comment: PyGame? Outdated? Just because the "new" download page is for a 2009 version, and has "official" binaries for installations python.org doesn't carry anymore and "experimental" binaries for the pre-installed Python in the upcoming OS X 10.7? :)

Comment: I guess the one thing I can do is just merge the entire soundtrack into one music file and then stream that whole thing. The queue doesn't really seem to work. Is is common for the documentation to be dated/wrong?

Comment: @JakeSmith: Have you tried MattDMo's suggestion? Or checked any of the stuff I mentioned in the comments on your question? For what it's worth, the last time I dealt with this (which is back when it was new), I spent half a day debugging what was going on with `set_endevent` and then realized it was easier to just do the next play on the `endevent` and not worry about the queue…